# Why is there something rather than nothing?

Tags: cosmology

Why is there something rather than nothing?

And before you answer "God did it," consider Carl Sagan's reply "then how did God come about?"

Comment: Way too off-topic. If there were nothing you woundn't ask (I is much more profound that it may seem).

Comment: Because. [ ](http://emp.ty)

Comment: This question should be closed...

Comment: Not a physics question, and I'd say it's a bad philosophy question. But then, I'm biased towards analytic philosophy.

Comment: Sydney Coleman and others published on this question, considering it really as the subquestion referring to why the apparent matter/antimatter asymmetry, which of course is now the subject of active experimentation.    Furthermore a subquestion could refer to the origin of inflation, assuming that it occurred.   I vote to edit the question and reopen.

Comment: @sigoldberg1: I'd also vote to reopen this question if it were edited into something more precise

Comment: I saw exactly the same question on atheism.stackexchange.com :) I would say there're some questions, answers to which are unknown, religious people may claim that they do have the answers, but they have no evidence behind them. In some world views the question itself isn't correct.

Comment: @sigoldberg--Yes and Coleman's paper was called "Why Is There Nothing Rather Than Something"---:)

Answer (score 2):

The question is unanswerable.  If I tell you "because P", then you can simply ask what caused P.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Manishearth: I actually think that this is as good an answer as can be provided to this question.  Any scientific explanation will have to rely on some general laws, and then the question would indeed become "but why do these laws hold?".

Comment: @YvanVelenik: True. This is why the question was closed, it really can't be answered properly via physics.